# CALayer delegation causes zombie crash -- why?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, core-animation

I am new to Core Animation and having trouble implementing a CALayer object with the drawLayer method in a delegate.

I have narrowed the problem down to a very simple test.  I have a main viewController named LBViewController that pushes a secondary viewController called Level2ViewController.  In the level 2 controller, in viewWillAppear:, I create a CALayer object with it's delegate=self (i.e. the level 2 controller).  Whether or not I actually implement the drawLayer:inContext: method I have the same problem -- when I return to the main viewController I get a zombie crash.  In the profiler it appears that the object in trouble is the level 2 viewController object -- which is being dealloc'ed after it's popped.

I've tried using a subclassed CALayer object instead of the delegate and it works fine.  If I comment out the delegate assignment it also runs fine.  I would like to understand why delegation is causing this problem.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Here's my code ---

**Level2ViewController**

```
@implementation Level2ViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    CALayer *box1 = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    box1.delegate = self;   // problem disappears if I comment out this assignment
    box1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    box1.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,200,300);
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:box1];
    [box1 setNeedsDisplay];

}

// makes no difference whether or not this method is defined as long
// as box1.delegate == self
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)theLayer inContext:(CGContextRef)theContext
{
    CGContextSaveGState(theContext);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(theContext, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(theContext, 3);
    CGContextAddRect(theContext, CGRectMake(5, 5, 40, 40));
    CGContextStrokePath(theContext);
    CGContextRestoreGState(theContext);
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

The method in **LBViewController** (the main controller) that pushes the level 2 view controller

```
- (IBAction)testAction:(id)sender {
    Level2ViewController *controller = [[Level2ViewController alloc]   
                                  initWithNibName:@"Level2ViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.title = @"Level2";

    // this push statement is where the profiler tells me the messaged zombie has been malloc'ed
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```

Comment: from what I can see on the documentation, CALayer delegate is usually a UIView, try doing box1.delegate = self.view;

Comment: I can't do that with the current structure of my program.  Because the delegate method is in the controller.  But I will try subclassing UIView and creating the CALayer object there, making the subclassed view the delegate.   I'll post the results when done.

Comment: okay sounds like a plan, but why don't you want to subclass CALayer?

Comment: I haven't yet designed my program -- so I may yet subclass CALayer.  right now I just want to understand what's going on so I have the option of delegating or subclassing.

Comment: I have subclassed UIView and set the subclassed object as the delegate.  With or without a drawLayer:inContext: method in the delegate, the program now crashes before it even displays the view.  Commenting out the delegate assignment solves the crash.   What am I missing?  I didn't see a protocol for the CALayer delegate -- are there any required methods to be implemented?

Comment: I have no idea why this is not working, http://www.voyce.com/index.php/2010/04/10/creating-an-ipad-flip-clock-with-core-animation/ this tutorial uses the same procedure to draw layers - also just give CALayer *box = [CALayer layer]; to create the layer maybe it will help(just making guesses though).

Comment: Using the layer method rather than alloc, init makes no difference.  My next guess would be to move the delegate draw method into a separate class altogether -- not a view and not a controller.   But instead of that, I'm going to give up trying to solve this problem for now and proceed by using subclassed CALayers -- I know that works.  Thanks for your advice.

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting? And if you think it's a zombies, have you tried to use the NSZombiesEnabled flag in Xcode, or use the zombies instrument?

Comment: When I mentioned the profiler in my original question, I _was_ referring to the zombie instrument.  See the comment in my code for the main viewController as to where the profiler points me. I assume that the push method makes a copy of the controller object at that point -- but the object is released once too many times. The fact that I have assigned this object as a delegate to the CALayer object must have something to do with the problem.

Comment: One more clue -- if I set the box1.delegate to nil in the level 2 viewWillDisapper method, the problem goes away.  I shouldn't have to do that, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to set the layer's delegate to `nil` before the delegate object is released. So in your `Leve2ViewController` do this:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (box1) {
        box1.delegate = nil;
    }
    box1 = nil;
}
```

Obviously this requires, that `box1` is turned into a field (so it is accessible in `viewWillDisappear:`)

Since you create `box1`in `viewWillAppear:` the code above uses `viewWillDisappear:`. Recently, when I ran into a similar problem, I had a separate delegate object in which I used `init` and `dealloc`.

Note: You call `[super viewDidAppear:animated];` in `viewWillAppear`. Looks like a typo or copy/paste glitch :-)